# Rails Devise: Sign In customizing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying to authenticate an admin panel.

If user not admin, cancel the request for sign in.

In default, if email/password is wrong. It renders `/users/sign_in`

```
  def create
    super do |user|
      if user.role >= 30
        res
      else
        #Do not create sessions, authenticate
        flash[:notice] = "You do not have permission"
        redirect_to :back
      end
    end
  end
```

Currently, It signs in no matter what i did.

How can i customize ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, This way worked for me.

I want to see better and easy solutions, if possible.

```
def create
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])
  if user.role >= 30
    super
  else
    render 'users/sessions/new'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard way will be to define a method say

```
def if_user_admin
  return user.role < 30
end
```

and adding this in your controller:

```
before_action :if_user_admin
```

Comment: Its not gonna help me, because that super creates me session anyway.